# Send results of mysql query via php post function

Tags: php, mysql

I am very inexperienced with PHP, just some basic understanding, and I am trying to send the results of a MySQL query via the post method to a specific URL. If I was displaying in a table on a web page then after the connection information I would have...

```
$result = mysql_query("select Selection, Date, Name from selectiontable order by Date");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Selection</th>
<th>Race</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Selection'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Instead of printing to a table I want to send this information via Post to a URL. I have searched high and low and can only seem to find information about how to send information that is being entered through a form. This query produces about 200 rows. Someone sent me the script below to adapt but I can't work out how to put the results of the query into it.

```
<?php 

$entries=(isset($_GET['entries']) ? $_GET['entries'] : '1');

echo '<h2>Send</h2>';
echo '<style> .over{clear:both; margin:5px; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px;}               label{display:block;} input {display:block; margin:5px 0 0 0;}</style>';
echo'<form method="post" action="http://www.domain.com" id="" name="">';


for ($i=0; $i < $entries; $i++) { 

echo '
<div class="over">
<div class="proof_type">
<label for="selection_'.$i.'">Selection</label>
<input name="selection_'.$i.'" value="" type="text" >
</div>

<div class="proof_type">
<label for="date_'.$i.'">Date</label>
<input name="date_'.$i.'" value="" type="text" >
</div>

<div class="proof_type">
<label for="name_'.$i.'">Name</label>
<input name="name_'.$i.'" value="" type="text" >
</div>
</div>
';

}

echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />';
echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" />';
echo'</form>';


?>
```

I would be very appreciative of any assistance. Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: you can't send post data WITHOUT a form (ajax calls notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send information through a URL, it will be received through the `GET` method. Otherwise you will need a library like `cURL` to accomplish this.